# Calculando colunas com condicional em R

Tags: r

Tenho a seguinte tabela `df`

```
Valor DebCred
100     C
200     D
300     C
```

Tenho que criar uma logica que é o seguinte se Tabela `DebCred` for `C` tenho que multiplicar `Valor * -1,00` e se for igual a `D` multiplicar `Valor*0`.

Fiz um código que seria o seguinte

```
IF (df$DebCred == C){
    df$Cred <- df$Valor * -1
}else{
    df$Cred <- df$Valor * 0 
}
IF (df$DebCred == D){
    df$Deb <- df$Valor * 1
}else{
    df$Deb <- df$Valor * 0 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma maneira vetorizada é a seguinte. Utiliza índices lógicos para modificar a coluna `Valor`.

```
df$Valor[df$DebCred == 'C'] <- -1*df$Valor[df$DebCred == 'C']
df$Valor[df$DebCred == 'D'] <- 1*df$Valor[df$DebCred == 'D']
df$Valor[!df$DebCred %in% c('C', 'D')] <- 0

df
#  Valor DebCred
#1  -100       C
#2   200       D
#3  -300       C
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira eficiente de tratar esses casos é com a função `mutate()`, do `tydiverse`.

Segue o código:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(Valor = c(100, 200, 300),
                DebCred = c("C", "D", "C"))

df %>% mutate(result = case_when(DebCred == "C" ~ Valor*-1,
                                 DebCred == "D" ~ Valor*0))

  Valor DebCred result
1   100       C   -100
2   200       D      0
3   300       C   -300
```

Caso sua intensão fosse armazenar o resultados na coluna `Valor` em vez de criar uma nova coluna, basta dentro do mutate fazer o seguinte:

```
df %>% mutate(Valor = case_when(DebCred == "C" ~ Valor*-1,
                                DebCred == "D" ~ Valor*0))
 Valor DebCred
  -100       C
     0       D
  -300       C
```